# The two constraints lead to an infeasible solution on CPLEX

Tags: cplex

I'm trying to modeling scheduling problem.

However, developing the model as shown below led to an infeasible solution.

There is a conflict between constraints 1 and 2, and I don't know how to resolve it.

I would really appreciate your help.

```
// indices and sets
 range I = 1..24; //staff
 range T = 1..24; //times
 {string} D = {"Rooms", "F&B", "Banquet"}; //department
 range W = 1..2; //work

 tuple m_tdw{
   key int t;
   key string d;
   key int w;
   float value;
 }
 
 {m_tdw} m_ = ...;

 // The number of people needed to process task W in department D at time T.
 float manpower[t in T][d in D][w in W] = item(m_, <t, d, w>).value; 

 //decision variables
 dvar boolean X[I][T][D][W]; // 1 if employee i is assigned to work on task w in department d at time t, or 0
 dvar boolean Y[I]; // 1 when employee i is assigned, or 0

 minimize sum(i in I, t in T, d in D, w in W)(20000*X[i][t][d][w])+sum(i in I)Y[i]*1000000;

  subject to{

   // 1. daily working time cons
   forall(i in I)
     sum(t in T, d in D, w in W)
       X[i][t][d][w] <= 8;
      
   // 2. Constraint to ensure that if x is 1 at time t+1, then x is also 1 at time t
   forall(i in I, t in 1..23)
     sum(d in D, w in W) X[i][t][d][w] >= sum(d in D, w in W) X[i][t+1][d][w];

   //Constraints for staffing needs
   forall(t in T, d in D, w in W)
     sum(i in I)
       X[i][t][d][w] >= manpower[t][d][w]; 

   //Constraints for calculating fixed costs when staffing
   forall(i in I, t in T, d in D, w in W)
     M*Y[i] >= X[i][t][d][w];
}
```

I tried to change the 2nd constraint to the following, but it still gave me an infeasible solution.

```
forall(i in I, t in 1..23)
sum(d in D, w in W) (X[i][t][d][w]+ X[i][t+1][d][w]) <= sum(d in D, w in W) (X[i][t+1][d][w]+ X[i][t+2][d][w]);
```

Comment: Looks like your constraint 2 will force any staff to work from T=1 onwards until they stop working. If there is any demand after T=8 that would be icompatible with a max 8 periods (hours?) working. If you comment out your constraint 1, what working patterns / solutions do you get?

Comment: I try not to limit the time when employees start working. 

However, I do want to constrain the task times to be joined.

For example, if employee #4 starts working at t=3, I want X_3,3,d,w, X_3,4,d,w, and X_3,5,d,w to all be 1 when he has worked 2 hours.